# DIV show-hide flickering in IE only

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dreamweaver, flicker

I've got a problem with showing images triggered by a MouseOver (see: http://camera.vu.nl/v2)
In Safari and Firefox it's ok. In IE when you move of the text onto the Visible background layer with the blob-image, the layer is turned on and off leading to flickering.
I build it using the standard options in Dreamweaver CS4.

Can anyone please help me avoid this flicker in IE without destroying the idea of the page?

Thanks ever so much!

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem when I've added a mouseover and mouse out on a div which showed a div which covered the div which had the mouseout event set.

Is this the case? If so, then when the div shows, it will fire the mouse out event and then end up in a loop on mouseover and mouseout until you truly move the pointer out.

if not, could you post some code sample?

Comment: Yes Jimmeh, that is (I think) what happens.
This is the code:

function MM_showHideLayers() { //v9.0
  var i,p,v,obj,args=MM_showHideLayers.arguments;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) 
  with (document) if (getElementById && ((obj=getElementById(args[i]))!=null)) { v=args[i+2];
    if (obj.style) { obj=obj.style; v=(v=='show')?'visible':(v=='hide')?'hidden':v; }
    obj.visibility=v; }
}

Standard Dreamweaver Behavior scripts.

Comment: This is in the body (just one of the lines):


and this is in the body:
<div class="rectangle_vis_12" id="b12" onmouseover="MM_showHideLayers('i12','','show','i22','','show','i32','','show','i42','','show')" onmouseout="MM_showHideLayers('i12','','hide','i22','','hide','i32','','hide','i42','','hide')">
    <p>eHealth</p>
    </div>

You can view the page on http://cameravu.nl/v2

Thx!!!